# TypeError: _onRequestWithOpts is not a function at Object.httpsProvider._onRequestWithOpts

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I'm creating an app that uses firebase-functions.  I created my app directory and ran firebase init.  After that was completed I tried to run the hello world program that it gives you using firebase serve, and I get this error:

```
TypeError: _onRequestWithOpts is not a function
at Object.httpsProvider._onRequestWithOpts
```

from what it looks like, it seems to be an issue with the onRequest() method but I have made apps using this before and have never ran into this issue.  I literally didn't change a single piece of code that they initially give you so unless they decided to change something overnight i'm not sure what the issue is.

using firebase deploy works, but firebase serve does not.  Using express and adding new functions, the error pops up when running firebase deploy and serve.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase- 
functions
//
exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) 
=> {
response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});

    Gabriels-MacBook-Pro:functions Mike$ firebase serve

    === Serving from '/Users/Gabe/Desktop/mycart-functions'...

   ⚠  Your requested "node" version "8" doesn't match your global 
    version "10"
    ✔  functions: Emulator started at http://localhost:5000
    i  functions: Watching "/Users/Gabe/Desktop/mycart- 
   functions/functions" for Cloud Functions...
   ⚠  TypeError: _onRequestWithOpts is not a function
    at Object.httpsProvider._onRequestWithOpts 
   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase- 
  tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:278:24)
    at Object.httpsProvider.onRequest 
   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase- 
  tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:283:34)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Gabe/Desktop/mycart- 
   functions/functions/index.js:6:39)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js 
   (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
   ⚠  We were unable to load your functions code. (see above)
```

Comment: If you're having problems with the Firebase CLI, post an issue to GitHub, not Stack Overflow. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56947574/cant-test-cloud-functions-locally-emulator-fails-to-start-with-typeerror-onr