# Can't test cloud functions locally, emulator fails to start with TypeError: _onRequestWithOpts is not a function

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

When I try to start the shell for local testing from the functions directory in my project, the emulator starts but my functions are not able to be loaded.

When I run "npm run build" I receive no errors. What is happening?

I have tried removing the functions directory and creating it again using the firebase-tools cli but I still get the same error. I have also exported the admin credentials.

I'm using the default method created in the index.ts file generated from the firebase-tools cli.

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

admin.initializeApp();
// // Start writing Firebase Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/typescript
//
export const helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, 
response) => {
 response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});
```

I expect the emulator to spin up instances of the function for testing but instead, I see this error:

```
✔  functions: Emulator started at http://localhost:5001
⚠  TypeError: _onRequestWithOpts is not a function
at Object.httpsProvider._onRequestWithOpts (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:278:24)
at Object.httpsProvider.onRequest (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:283:34)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Volumes/G-DRIVE mobile USB-C/CLEAN UP/Documents/code_bank/typescript/theincrowdapp/functions/lib/index.js:9:38)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
⚠  We were unable to load your functions code. (see above)
   - It appears your code is written in Typescript, which must be compiled before emulation.
   - You may be able to run "npm run build" in your functions directory to resolve this.
```

Comment: If you're having problems with the Firebase CLI, post an issue to GitHub, not Stack Overflow.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Comment: i also face this problem after updating to the newest version

Comment: I receive the same error

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you are experiencing this error, run `npm install firebase-functions@3.0.2` in your `functions` directory.

This will be fixed soon, and you can follow along here:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1480

Comment: I had to update firebase-tools to the latest version for this to work.

Answer (score 2):

I found error in:

node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js

line 276:

```
const _onRequestWithOpts = httpsProvider._onRequestWithOpts;
```

should be:

```
const _onRequestWithOpts = httpsProvider._onRequestWithOptions;
```

Answer (score 1):

I've faced this error a year ago and faced it again yesterday despite the fact I updated firebase-funcitons to latest.

I had to update firebase-tools as well with `npm i -g firebase-tools@latest`

And the last thing you need to do is to close your command line/open a new tab so that latest version is used

To sum up:

1. `npm i firebase-functions@latest`
2. `npm i -g firebase-tools@latest`
3. close and open the command line

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade firebasefunction  to version 3.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Delete **node_modules** then run **npm install**, **npm install firebase-admin** and ***npm install firebase-functions@3.0.2***

Answer (score 0):

If you have updated `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` recently and not restarted `iTerm or Terminal` quit and restart it. i did that, it worked perfectly.

your terminal has to be restarted after updating `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` simple.. this could help someone somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue but got it working with the latest version of firebase-* packages by doing the following.

1. Firebase -> settings -> service accounts "Generate new private key" and save your file under your functions directory. Try naming it to something such as "service-account.json".
2. On your command line (Mac for example) run "export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=<service_account_file_path>"
3. Modify tsconfig.json "strict":false, "noImplicitAny": false,"
4. Voila!